# Download image by using Grape and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, grape-api

I in my `app/api/myapp/api.rb` file I'm writing simple registration method:

```
params do
  requires :email, type: String,  regexp: /.+@.+/, allow_blank: false
  requires :password, type: String, allow_blank: false
  requires :name, type: String, allow_blank: false
  requires :surname, type: String, allow_blank: false
  requires :person, type: Integer, allow_blank: false
end
post :register do
    User.create!(email: params[:email],
                 password: params[:password],
                 name: params[:name],
                 surname: params[:surname],
                 remote_avatar_url: Faker::Avatar.image)
end
```

As you can see, I'm using carrierwave gem to keep images of my model `User`. Now I'm just assigning random image from Faker gem.

How to receive image, that is sent from client and assign it to my new Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile` as the example below.

```
desc 'Upload Image.'
params do
    requires :file, :type => Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile
    requires :id, :type => Integer
end
post ':id/avatar' do
    File.open(params[:file].tempfile, 'r') do |f|
        # Do whatever you need with this file. 
        # Here, you can store it in the server filesystem or in your database.
    end
end
```

Comment: can you write example with `create!` method?

Comment: Using the provided example you have access to the file. You can get its filename and save it as a attribute of your model.